# How to do integration/functional tests with celery tasks in Flask

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, flask, celery

I'm working with Celery for the first time.  I have some api endpoints that will launch a celery task to send an email.  All well and good- I know how to write unit tests to ensure the task works properly and to make sure the endpoint calls it properly (with the task mocked out).

However, I believe in writing integration tests that don't mock anything out.  It is simple enough to call the endpoint in a test and watch the output from a celery worker if I run it in a console... but how do I automate that if the worker is running as a daemon?